# How can I define a function with a parameter dependent on a symbol debug?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, compiler-flags, compiler-options

I defined with [-D](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) compiler option a symbol debug: -DDEBUG_VALUE.
I would like a function in which the presence of a parameter depends on the definition or less of the symbol debug flag.

Namely if DEBUG_VALUE is defined, I have

```
my_function(int parameter1, int  my_parameter_dependent)
```

Otherwise

```
my_function(int parameter1)
```

In this way

```
my_function(int parameter1  #ifdef DEBUG_VALUE , int my_parameter_dependent #endif)
```

I get

```
error: stray ‘#’ in program
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘ifdef’
```

How can I solve it?

(I'm on a C++ compiler on a Unix system.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure preprocessor directives have to be on their own line

Comment: @Justin Thus, I can't in no other way??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare the function differently...

```
 #if defined( DEBUG_VALUE )
     void my_function( int parameter1, int my_parameter_dependent );
 #else
     void my_function( int parameter1 );
 #endif
```

Create an embedded macro

```
 # if defined( DEBUG_VALUE )
         #define DEPENDENT_PARAM( x )   x
 # else
         #define DEPENDENT_PARAM( x )
 #endif
 void my_function( int parameter1  DEPENDENT_PARAM(, int my_parameter_dependent) );
```

This means that the text within the macro is munched by the preprocessor, and is hidden

Or you can declare debug data

```
  #if defined( DEBUG_VALUE )
      #define EXTRA_DEBUG  , int my_parameter_dependent
  #else
      #define EXTRA_DEBUG
  #endif
  void my_function( int parameter1 EXTRA_DEBUG );
```

They all have their merits, depending on flexibility and how many functions are changed.

Comment: `DEPENDENT_PARAM` strikes me as a good solution to this particular problem (though under the circumstances, I think a different name like `DEBUG_PARAM` would probably be better).

Comment: I'd rather call it `DEBUG_ONLY`, since its use isn't limited to parameters. In fact, having `_PARAM` there in the name would be confusing to me, because I might be tempted to omit the comma delimiter. (Warning: MFC has such a `DEBUG_ONLY` macro, so beware of possible name clashes.)

Answer (score 4):

You can't embed a preprocessor macro *within* a line. They require a dedicated line of their own. So you have to break this declaration up onto separate lines:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_VALUE
    void my_function(int parameter1, int my_parameter_dependant);
#else
    void my_function(int parameter1);
#endif
```

Or, if you want to get clever and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), take advantage of C++'s great flexibility with regard to statements and whitespace:

```
void my_function(int parameter1
#ifdef DEBUG_VALUE
                , int my_parameter_dependant
#endif
                );
```

Comment: A 3rd way is with an appropriately defined helper macro: `void my_function(int parameter1 DEBUG_VALUE_ONLY(int my_parameter_dependent))`.

Comment: Hmm yeah, the only thing better than 1 macro is 2 macros!

Comment: @CodyGray Excellent, your second solution. I knew the first solution but it did not matter because I would have to replicate many lines of code. The second way works. Thanks.

Comment: I strongly recommend against the second version; it tends to reduce understanding even more than the first. Regardless, preprocessor trickery like this can easily get hard to understand, especially once you start wanting yet another configuration

Comment: @Justin I use it in debug mode alone. When the code will be ready for release this preprocessor directive will disappear.